# How to create an object in one file and use everywhere in Django?

Tags: python, django

Let's take an example of this snippet

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('myapp')
```

This has to be there in every file of my Django project in which I am using. There can be several other imports, that will be used in every file of the project. Is there any file or place in Django where I can declare these snippets once, and use the variable `log` and the others everywhere in the project without any imports or as minimum import as possible?

Comment: Put this in __init__.py

Comment: I think, you must use explicit imports in every module which you'll need.

Comment: @BipulJain I'll try that

Comment: @BipulJain putting it in `__init__.py` of the main project folder didn't work

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, although I don't think it's good style. Even though you have complete control over the names in `includes.py`, you are still cluttering up your namespace for the sake of saving a bit of typing, and sooner or later it will bite you. Also, "Explicit is better than implicit".

includes.py:

```
from json import  loads, dumps
# and anything else you want widely defined
```

test.py: and any other files where you want to use loads or dumps

```
from includes import *
print dumps([{},{}] )  # which works
```

Comment: Yes, I am doing this itself, but, I was interested to know if there was any Django specific way to do this.